# How do I read a line and set it as a intager withouth its brackets

Tags: bash

I have written a script which reads a line in a text and gives the text as output. The text is only a number but it is in brackets. Because of that I can't set it as a intager. How do I make scripot to read the file without brackets or make it delete the brackets afterwards?
My script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
P=`cat /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light`
echo "$P"
```

Comment: Add output of `cat /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light` to your question.

Comment: What is the output of this script?

Comment: it's (29,0) and I need to write it withouth brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
P=`cat /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light`
```

by

```
P=`cat /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light | tr -d '()'`
```

to delete all `(` and `)` or shorter

```
P=`tr -d '()' < /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light`
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you show how can I set it as a intager too?

Comment: Use first `declare -i P` to set integer attribute but `29,0` is no integer. `29` and `0` are integers.